# SQL 11g Pivot Tables

Tags: sql, oracle11g

OK ... so I've been trying to understand pivot commands all day and just cannot get to grips with it.

The following script gives me the months and year (MON-YYYY) listed from the component start date to the current date for 3 components (P_CATNR).

```
select x.*, nrb.p_catnr, pd.catnr
from 
    (select to_char( add_months( start_date, level-1 ),'Mon-YYYY') Month_from_NR 
    from (select (select min(selection_relse_date) 
                     from BDS_SELECTION_ORG@sid_to_cdsuk st 
                         where substr(selection_no, 2, 99) = '2EDVD0017') start_date, sysdate end_date from dual)
                            connect by level <= months_between(trunc(end_date,'MM'), trunc(start_date,'MM'))+1) x,
            part_description pd 
 INNER JOIN inventory_purchase ip 
         ON ip.part_no = pd.part_no 
 INNER JOIN scm_prodtyp pt 
         ON pt.prodtyp = pd.prodtyp 
 INNER JOIN oes_fod_match acp 
         ON acp.part_no = pd.part_no 
 INNER JOIN NCF_COMPPART ncf 
         ON ncf.item_part_no = pd.part_no 
 INNER JOIN oes_nrbom nrb 
         ON ncf.catnr = nrb.c_catnr 
        AND ncf.prodtyp = nrb.c_prodtyp 
        AND ncf.packtyp = nrb.c_packtyp 
        AND ncf.vernr = nrb.c_vernr 
      WHERE pd.cunr in ('649830', 'W30000') 
        AND pd.catnr = '2EDVD0017' 
        AND pd.fod_idc = 'Y' 
        AND pt.prodgrp = 'AW'
```

What I would like to do have is the MONTH_FROM_NR listed per column, i.e.

[image]

Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with t as (
select x.*, nrb.p_catnr, pd.catnr
from 
    (select to_char( add_months( start_date, level-1 ),'Mon-YYYY') Month_from_NR 
    from (select (select min(selection_relse_date) 
                     from BDS_SELECTION_ORG@sid_to_cdsuk st 
                         where substr(selection_no, 2, 99) = '2EDVD0017') start_date, sysdate end_date from dual)
                            connect by level <= months_between(trunc(end_date,'MM'), trunc(start_date,'MM'))+1) x,
            part_description pd 
 INNER JOIN inventory_purchase ip 
         ON ip.part_no = pd.part_no 
 INNER JOIN scm_prodtyp pt 
         ON pt.prodtyp = pd.prodtyp 
 INNER JOIN oes_fod_match acp 
         ON acp.part_no = pd.part_no 
 INNER JOIN NCF_COMPPART ncf 
         ON ncf.item_part_no = pd.part_no 
 INNER JOIN oes_nrbom nrb 
         ON ncf.catnr = nrb.c_catnr 
        AND ncf.prodtyp = nrb.c_prodtyp 
        AND ncf.packtyp = nrb.c_packtyp 
        AND ncf.vernr = nrb.c_vernr 
      WHERE pd.cunr in ('649830', 'W30000') 
        AND pd.catnr = '2EDVD0017' 
        AND pd.fod_idc = 'Y' 
        AND pt.prodgrp = 'AW'
)
select * from t pivot(
    max(catnr) catnr 
    for month_from_nr 
        in (to_date('10-2007', 'DD-YYYY') as d102007,  to_date('11-2007', 'DD-YYYY') as d112007)
);
```

You'll see these columns
p_catnr, catnr_d102007, catnr_d112007

I used max(catnr) because I don't know the nature of the column catnr

You have to write IN clause manually or you can use PIVOT XML. In this case you can use subqueries in IN clause, but the query will return xml data in this case

An example of PIVOT XML

```
with t as (
select 'James' name, '2010' dt_year, 100 salary from dual
union all select 'James', '2011', 200 salary from dual
union all select 'James', '2012', 300 salary from dual
union all select 'Lisa', '2012', 450 salary from dual
)
select name, dt_year_xml from t pivot xml (
  sum(salary) sal for dt_year in (select distinct dt_year from t)
);
```

Comment: Hi, is the IN clause setting the date period? can I change the date period by adding a select statement to define the start date and use sysdate (current date) as the end date?

I tried ...         

    in (to_date((select min(selection_relse_date) 
    from BDS_SELECTION_ORG@sid_to_cdsuk st 
    where substr(selection_no, 2, 99) = '2EDVD0017'), 'DD-YYYY') as d102007,  to_date(sysdate, 'DD-YYYY') as d112007)

... but got this error ...

ORA-56901: non-constant expression is not allowed for pivot|unpivot values

Comment: @SMORF IN clause defines columns, I'll try to explain in the answer. I've already written in the answer that you cannot use subquery (= SELECT) in the IN clause. If you want to use SELECT you should use PIVOT XML instead of PIVOT, but the result won't be columns, but XML for each row.

Comment: @SMORF I added the example how you can use SELECT inside IN clause

Comment: OK, it's finally clicked! Many thanks for your explanation (and you patience).